# Clobber everything to do with a package

Tags: package-management

I'm looking for a way to just remove every last trace of NodeJS and NPM anywhere on my system -- everything! I'm not concerned about losing data... I just want my system to be exactly as if I had never installed or downloaded NodeJS and NPM.

Is there any way to do that? Assuming I've installed multiple versions by multiple means including building from source...

...FYI this is not a question about NodeJS or NPM.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a automated way to do this. Especially if you didn't use your distributions' method for managing packages. You'll have to search for nodejs and NPM related directories and manually delete them.

I would make note if files that are consistently in a nodejs deployment and search for those. If they're in directories that are clearly marked as node or NPM specific, then you should be able to remove these in a wholesale fashion using `rm -fr <somedir>`.